# Angular - How to post pre-filled input data by submitting a from with NgForm

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

I really need a help to find a solution.

when this app is opened, it loads data from database and it goes into the select options.

and when you select an option, it will automatically fill out input fields.  no problem up until here.

but when you press the submit button and try to send data back to database, the problem happens.

I looked into console.log but there were no values(only keys there) but if you manually type input fields, there are values and everything is working fine.

I really don't know how to find a correct solution to this issue.

----HTML----

```
<form ngForm #f=ngForm (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(f)" class="d-flex justify-content-center" >

<div ngModelGroup="pickup" id="pickupContainer" class="d-flex justify-content-between" >
                <div id="container_left">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                        <label for="PickupAddrBook" class="input-group-text" >Address Book</label>
                        <select class="input-group-append"  id="PickupAddrBook" type="text"  
                        (change)="OnChange($event,pickupCompany,pickupAddr1,pickupAddr2,pickupSuburb,pickupContact)">
                            <option value="">---Address Book(clear)---</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let item of addrBook[0]" value="">{{item.code}} : {{item.compnay}}{{item.addr1}}{{item.addr2}}{{item.suburb}}</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                        <label for="pickupCompany" class="input-group-text" >Company</label>
                        <input #pickupCompany #pickupCompany=ngModel class="input-group-append" ngModel name="pickupCompany" id="pickupCompany" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                        <label for="pickupAddr1" class="input-group-text" >Address Line 1</label>
                        <input #pickupAddr1 class="input-group-append" ngModel name="pickupAddr1" id="pickupAddr1" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                        <label for="pickupAddr2" class="input-group-text" >Address Line 2</label>
                        <input #pickupAddr2 class="input-group-append" ngModel name="pickupAddr2" id="pickupAddr2" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                        <label for="pickupSuburb" class="input-group-text" >Suburb</label>
                        <input #pickupSuburb class="input-group-append" ngModel name="pickupSuburb" id="pickupSuburb" type="text">
                    </div>        
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                        <label for="pickupContact" class="input-group-text" >Contact</label>
                        <input #pickupContact class="input-group-append" ngModel name="pickupContact" id="pickupContact" type="text">
                    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<form>
```

--- TS---

```
 OnChange($event,pickupCompany,pickupAddr1,pickupAddr2,pickupSuburb,pickupContact
    ) {
    if ($event.target.selectedIndex==0) {
      pickupCompany.value= "";
      pickupAddr1.value= "";
      pickupAddr2.value= "";
      pickupSuburb.value= "";
      pickupContact.value= "";
    }else{   
    let i:number = $event.target.selectedIndex-1;

    pickupCompany.value= this.addrBook[0][i].company;
    pickupAddr1.value= this.addrBook[0][i].addr1;
    pickupAddr2.value= this.addrBook[0][i].addr2;
    pickupSuburb.value= this.addrBook[0][i].suburb;
    pickupContact.value= this.addrBook[0][i].contact;

    }
```

Comment: value: Object
basic: {Driver: "", BookedBy: "", ReqDate: undefined, ReqTime: ""}
delivery: {deliveryCompany: "", deliveryAddr1: "", deliveryAddr2: "", deliverySuburb: "", deliveryContact: ""}
pickup: {pickupCompany: "", pickupAddr1: "", pickupAddr2: "", pickupSuburb: "", pickupContact: "", …}    no values like this :(

Comment: what is addrBook data? why are using two dimensional array -this.addrBook[0][i].contact;

Comment: That is console.log (NgForm.value). As you see, there is no valuse.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "ngForm" to your

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(f)" class="d-flex justify-content-center" >
```